# Django how to get inbound data of html fields when not using froms in views?

Tags: django

I am using Django default login in my views. When user typing wrong password or username then it's showing the error message but the data those entered by user are disappeared. I want to to keep the wrong data in my html username and password fields. here is my views.py:

```
def login_view(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated:
         return redirect('blog:my-account')
     else:
         if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password =request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('blog:my-account')
            elif username == "": 
                messages.info(request, "Please enter username")
            
            elif password == "":
                messages.info(request, "Please enter password")
            
            else:
                messages.info(request, "Please enter right password or username")
            
     context = {}
     return render(request, 'members/login.html',context)
```

my html fields for username and password:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="your_name" placeholder="username"/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="your_pass" placeholder="Password"/>
```

I tried this but didn't work :

```
    ..... 
       else:
            messages.info(request, "Please enter right password or username")
    ......... 
    
  # then trying this code for get inbound value   
  inboud_username = username
  inboud_password = password  
  print('####username: ',inboud_username) 
  print('####password: ',inboud_password)     
  context ={'inboud_username':inboud_username,'inboud_password':inboud_password}
  return render(request, 'members/login.html',context)
```

**#html**

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="your_name" placeholder="username" {% if inboud_username.is_bound %}value="{{ inboud_username.value }} {% endif %}"/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="your_pass" placeholder="Password" {% if inboud_password.is_bound %}value="{{  inboud_password.value }} {% endif %}"/>
```

I am seeing the inbound username and password in my console
[image]

Comment: For `inboud_username = username` and `inboud_password = password`  are they actually passing values at all? Print both to and check if there are values in the console.

Comment: @Moi Myazz yes I am getting the inboud_username and inboud_password in my console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are seeing results in the console then it is how you are using the variables in the template...

Where you have `{% if inboud_username.is_bound %}` for example is causing the problem:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="your_name" placeholder="username" {% if inboud_username.is_bound %}value="{{ inboud_username.value }} {% endif %}"/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="your_pass" placeholder="Password" {% if inboud_password.is_bound %}value="{{  inboud_password.value }} {% endif %}"/>
```

I think you might want to try `{% if inboud_username %}` as this is the way you have passed the variable `context ={'inboud_username':inboud_username,'inboud_password':inboud_password}`

Please update to:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="your_name" placeholder="username" {% if inboud_username %}value="{{ inboud_username }}" {% endif %}/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="your_pass" placeholder="Password" {% if inboud_password %}value="{{ inboud_password }}" {% endif %}/>
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)